# Trying to run preview of my sveltekit blog

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to run preview of my blog I made using sveltekit by typing npm run preview in console, but I keep getting the following error. I'm following a tutorial, but nowhere in the tutorial mentions a manifest.js file nor did the tutorial creator even receive this error, and I can't find the manifest.js file its talking about, what can I do here?

`error when starting preview server: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\darre\my-svelte-project\.svelte-kit\output\server\manifest.js' imported from C:\Users\darre\my-svelte-project\node_modules\.pnpm\@sveltejs+kit@1.21.0_svelte@4.0.0_vite@4.3.9\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\exports\vite\preview\index.js at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5) at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11) at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10) at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11) at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28) at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30) at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18) at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22) at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:110:35) at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)`

I've tried locating the file and trying to figure out what it's needed for to no success.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `npm build` first, as mentioned [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/building-your-app)

Comment: So what exactly to do I do here then? I'm sorry I'm very new to all this and I just wanted to jump in and get started on a project, I tried doing npm run build and it seemed to go fine, but once I tried npm run preview again I ran into the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, it's a bit too vague, there can be multiple issues. Whenever I get a problem like this, I usually reset.

I would suggest making a new sveltekit project, and start off with something simple, like just a page with "hello world" or something. Then `npm run build` and `npm run preview` should work on it.

After that gradually make small incremental changes to the project (so that it becomes closer and closer to what you have now), and then build and preview all the little changes. At some point it will break, that's when you'll get your "Aha!" moment.